# How to get the IP address of a known hostname in Linux?

Tags: networking, ip, linux-networking, hostname

I have a device in a public network (I'm not the owner/admin of the WiFi) and I want to know if there is a way to get the devices IP address by knowing its hostname from a second device in the same network?

Comment: Use the command `host hostname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multicast DNS protocol is designed to do exactly that. You simply append `.local` after the hostname of the device and you have a name that you can use with all the usual commands. For example:

```
ssh hostname.local
```

Answer (score 3):

If the network has a DNS service, query that for the hostname using a tool like `host` or `dig`. This will depend on the device being registered, either statically, by a DHCP service, or by dynamic registration on the device itself.

Many public networks do not do this for avoidance of cost & needless complexity and/or privacy preservation reasons. In that case, consult the network operator, who can infer this data from logs on relevant hardware devices (DHCP server, gateway, etc.).